# Send emails to multiple domains via wordpress

Tags: php, email, smtp, wordpress

I have a small Digital Ocean VPS that at the moment is configured with 2 small and WordPress websites.

I want both WordPress instalations to be able to send emails via zoho.com. (DNS is configured correctly on both domains and both point to zoho.com on the MX record).

For my domain I managed to configure sSMTP to successfully send emails but sSMTP seems to be sort of a one-account configuration.

How would go about configuring the server so that both WordPress instalations with different domains can send email successfully to zoho.com?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably recommend using a plugin on each WordPress site, such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/, instead of configuring it on the server with sSMTP.

Also, make sure that you have proper SPF records in place (although I guess that's mostly a moot point if you're using SMTP).